# Python Plot X Access Time Values Not Formatted Correctly

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I have a large amount of data in CSV Format that looks like this:

```
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:05 +0000 2015', u'anx321', 'RT @ManojHarry27: If India loses 2015 worldcup, Karishma\ntanna will be held responsible !!! #BB8', '0.0453125', '0.325')
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:13 +0000 2015', u'FrancisKimberl3', 'Python form imploration overgrowth-the consummative the very best as representing construction upsurge: sDGy', '1.0', '0.39')
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:18 +0000 2015', u'AllTechBot', 'RT @ruby_engineer: A workshop on monads with C++14 http://t.co/OKFc91J0QJ #hacker #rubyonrails #python #AllTech', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:22 +0000 2015', u'python_job', ' JOB ALERT  #ITJob #Job #New York - Senior Software Engineer Python Backed by First Round http://t.co/eqVxoMzYMG  view full details', '0.245454545455', '0.44595959596')
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:23 +0000 2015', u'weepingtaco', 'Python: basic but beautiful', '0.425', '0.5625')
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:27 +0000 2015', u'python_IT_jobs', ' JOB ALERT  #ITJob #Job #New York - Senior Software Engineer Python Backed by First Round http://t.co/gavWyraNqE  view full details', '0.245454545455', '0.44595959596')
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:32 +0000 2015', u'accusoftinfoway', 'RT @findmjob: DevOps Engineer http://t.co/NasdBEEnRp #aws #perl #mysql #linux #hadoop #python #Puppet #jobs #hiring #careers', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:32 +0000 2015', u'accusoftinfoway', 'RT @arnicas: Very useful - end to end deploying python flask on AWS RT @matt_healy: Great tutorial: https://t.co/RsiM09qJsJ #flask #python ', '0.595', '0.375')
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:36 +0000 2015', u'denisegregory10', "Oh you can't beat a good 'python' argument! http://t.co/ELo3GvNsuE via @youtube", '0.875', '0.6')
(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:38 +0000 2015', u'NoSQLDigest', 'RT @KirkDBorne: R and #Python starter code for participating in @BoozAllen #DataScience Bowl: http://t.co/Q5C01eya95 #abdsc #DataSciBowl #B', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:00:05 +0000 2015', u'RedditPython', '"academicmarkdown": a Python module for academic writing with Markdown. Haven\'t tried it o... https://t.co/uv8yFaz6cv http://t.co/EhiIIO7uTW', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:00:28 +0000 2015', u'shopawol', 'Only 8.5 and 12 left make sure to get yours \nhttp://t.co/4rxmHqP2Qs\n#wdywt #goawol #sneakerheads http://t.co/wACIOdlGwY', '0.166666666667', '0.62962962963')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:00:31 +0000 2015', u'AuthorBee', "RT @_kevin_ewb_: I know what your girl won't she just wanna kick it like the #WorldCup ", '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:00:37 +0000 2015', u'g33kmaddy', 'RT @KirkDBorne: R and #Python starter code for participating in @BoozAllen #DataScience Bowl: http://t.co/Q5C01eya95 #abdsc #DataSciBowl #B', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:00:45 +0000 2015', u'Altfashion', 'Photo: A stunning photo of Kaoris latex dreams beautiful custom python bra. Photographer: MagicOwenTog... http://t.co/KdWnr3I8xP', '0.675', '1.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:00:46 +0000 2015', u'oh226twt', 'Python programming: Easy and Step by step Guide for Beginners: Learn Python (English Edition) http://t.co/9optdOCrtE 1532', '0.216666666667', '0.416666666667')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:00:50 +0000 2015', u'DvSpacefest', 'RT @Pomerantz: Potential team in the Learning XPRIZE looking for Python coders. Details: https://t.co/nGgrmYmXCa', '0.0', '1.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:01:04 +0000 2015', u'cun45', 'SPORTS And More: #Cycling #Ciclismo  U23 #Portugal #WorldCup team o... http://t.co/FBeqatfu85', '0.5', '0.5')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:01:12 +0000 2015', u'insofferentexo', 'RT @FISskijumping: Dawid is already at the hill in Zakopane, in a larger than life format! #skijumping #worldcup http://t.co/SDOnxDwfIX', '0.0', '0.5')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:01:17 +0000 2015', u'beuhe', 'Madrid Tawarkan Khedira ke Dortmund: Real Madrid dikabarkan telah menawarkan Sami Khedira ... http://t.co/R5YCKjECtm #football #worldcup', '0.2', '0.3')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:01:18 +0000 2015', u'ITJobs_Karen', ' JOB ALERT  #ITJob #Job #Paradise Valley - Python / Django Developer http://t.co/0Xn1k0cL5B  view full details', '0.35', '0.55')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:01:22 +0000 2015', u'DonnerBella', 'So confused about #meninist . Monty Python, is that you?', '-0.4', '0.7')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:01:34 +0000 2015', u'DoggingTeens', '#Dogging,#OutdoorSex,#Sluts,#GangBang,#Stockings,#Uk_Sex: 13 Inch Black Python Being Sucked http://t.co/n9Yv4nhcxo', '-0.166666666667', '0.433333333333')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:03 +0000 2015', u'WorldCupFNH', 'Soccer-La Liga results and standings:  #FNH #WorldCup #Russia2018 #WC2018 http://t.co/3JOOnBQzvG', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:03 +0000 2015', u'WorldCupFNH', 'Soccer-La Liga summaries:  #FNH #WorldCup #Russia2018 #WC2018 http://t.co/AZgxr5Z9EV', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:03 +0000 2015', u'WorldCupFNH', "Soccer-Late Congo goal spoils Equatorial Guinea's party:  #FNH #WorldCup #Russia2018 #WC2018 http://t.co/W6Ff4HikxH", '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:04 +0000 2015', u'WorldCupFNH', 'Soccer-Ligue 1 top scorers:  #FNH #WorldCup #Russia2018 #WC2018 http://t.co/WS2lcZnzKu', '0.5', '0.5')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:04 +0000 2015', u'WorldCupFNH', 'Soccer-Pearce answers critics as Forest seal unlikely win:  #FNH #WorldCup #Russia2018 #WC2018 http://t.co/Qb5PKuls6z', '0.15', '0.45')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:04 +0000 2015', u'WorldCupFNH', 'Soccer-Israeli championship results and standings:  #FNH #WorldCup #Russia2018 #WC2018 http://t.co/dce9Qn9oI5', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:07 +0000 2015', u'Jeff88Ho', 'RT @artwisanggeni: #python jweede.recipe.template 1.2.3: Buildout recipe for making files out of Jinja2 templates http://t.co/dgeuuFWf19', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:07 +0000 2015', u'Jeff88Ho', 'RT @artwisanggeni: #python aclhound 1.7.5: ACL Compiler http://t.co/fNOFSYd7FJ', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:08 +0000 2015', u'Jeff88Ho', 'RT @artwisanggeni: #python Flask-Goat 0.2.0: Flask plugin for security and user administration via GitHub OAuth &amp; organization http://t.co/', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:08 +0000 2015', u'Jeff88Ho', 'RT @artwisanggeni: #python filewatch 0.0.6: Python File Watcher http://t.co/fIHLagCqvf', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:16 +0000 2015', u'HeatherA789', "Programming Python: Start Learning Python Today, Even If You've Never Coded Before (A Beginner's Guide): http://t.co/3Ss4cwCvP6", '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:18 +0000 2015', u'HeatherA789', 'Python: Learn Python in One Day and Learn It Well. Python for Beginners with Hands-on Project.: Python: Learn http://t.co/zvLIpydd6V', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:26 +0000 2015', u'AlexeiCherenkov', 'It looks like I should learn Python. Do you think I can do this during 3 hours tomorrow? Yes-Rt; No-Fav.', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:33 +0000 2015', u'cleansheet', "#WorldCup Cricket World Cup: Australia should've picked a leg-spinner and named Steve Smith vice-captain ... http://t.co/kgXgUVbHDd", '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:34 +0000 2015', u'cleansheet', '#WorldCup Younger Northug earns 1st cross-country World Cup victory http://t.co/y7jozMriFG', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:35 +0000 2015', u'cleansheet', '#WorldCup ICC World Cup 2015: School massacre survivors inspire Pakistan team http://t.co/Tj1jpCZsj6', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:35 +0000 2015', u'cleansheet', '#WorldCup We Want to Win World Cup for Peshawar Schoolkids: Misbah-ul-Haq http://t.co/RbeBkrv69s', '0.8', '0.4')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:38 +0000 2015', u'world_latest', 'New: Equatorial Guinea 1-1 Congo http://t.co/32sfrrbBOW #follow #worldcup world_latest world_latest', '0.136363636364', '0.454545454545')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:39 +0000 2015', u'FAHAD_CTID', 'RT @fawadiii: @FAHAD_CTID @VeronaPerqukuu Hahaha. Hanw ;) bdw worldcup bhi hai 15 sy :D', '0.483333333333', '0.8')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:43 +0000 2015', u'amazon_mybot', '#3: Python http://t.co/LLzeKQQBon', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:45 +0000 2015', u'LarryMesast', '#javascript #html5 #UX #Python #agile #DDD', '0.5', '0.75')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:02:46 +0000 2015', u'washim987', 'RT @anjali_damania: I was angry at @shaziailmi &amp; @thekiranbedi My husband calms me down &amp; says. Haame Worldcup jitna hai. Sirf Pakistan se ', '-0.327777777778', '0.644444444444')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:03:02 +0000 2015', u'sksh_rana', '"@ManojHarry27: If India loses 2015 worldcup, Karishma\ntanna will be held responsible !!! #BB8"\n@TheFarahKhan @BeingSalmanKhan', '0.0453125', '0.325')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:03:14 +0000 2015', u't_kohyama', '@_3mame PythonMatlabPython', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:03:16 +0000 2015', u'AntonShipulin', '#photo #worldcup #flowerceremony #sprint #Ruhpolding http://t.co/fe9qpiwsqJ', '0.0', '0.0')
(u'Sat Jan 17 19:03:22 +0000 2015', u'karthik_vik', 'RT @ValaAfshar: Highest paying programming languages, ranked by salary:\n\n1 Ruby\n2 Objective C\n3 Python\n4 Java\n\nhttp://t.co/RudytdjFLC http:', '0.0', '0.1')
```

Right now I plot the data with the following script:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') 
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import matplotlib.dates as mdates  
from pylab import *             
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil
from dateutil import parser
import re
import os
import operator
import csv

input_filename="test_output.csv"
output_image_namep='polarity.png'
output_image_name2='subjectivity.png'

input_file = open(input_filename, 'r')

data = csv2rec(input_file, names=['time', 'name', 'message', 'polarity', 'subjectvity'])  

time_list = []
polarity_list = []

''' I am aware there's a much more concise way of doing this'''

for line in data:
    td = line['time']

    ''' stupid regex '''
    s = re.sub('\(\u', '', td)
    dtime = parser.parse(s)
    dtime = re.sub('-', '', str(dtime))
    dtime = re.sub(' ', '', dtime)
    dtime = re.sub('\+00:00', '', dtime)
    dtime = re.sub(':', '', dtime)
    dtime = dtime[:-2]

    try:
        subjectivity = float(line['subjectivity'].replace("'", '').replace(")", ''))

    except:
        pass

    print dtime, polarity

    time_list.append( str(dtime) )
    polarity_list.append( polarity )

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 4                              
rcParams['font.size'] = 8                                       

fig = plt.figure()                                              

plt.plot([time_list], [polarity_list], 'ro')
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([-1,1])

plt.savefig(output_image_namep)
```

It ends up looking like:

[image]

Which is fine but **I would like the X axis to display the date labels correctly**. Right now I'm doing some ugly regex to strip the date down to YYYYMMDDHHMM.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
import time

def format_time_label(original):
    return time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M', 
                         time.strptime(original, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"))
```

Example:

```
>>> format_time_label('Sat Jan 17 19:00:50 +0000 2015')
'201501171900'
```

This works only if every date in your data has timezone offset `+0000`, as there seems to be no code in Python standard library to recognize this.

You can change parsing format expression accordingly to account for leftovers from your data format:

```
def format_time_label(original):
    return time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M', 
                         time.strptime(original, "(u'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'"))

>>> format_time_label("(u'Sat Jan 17 18:56:05 +0000 2015'")
'201501171856'
```